# getting user input - shell programming

Tags: shell

I am trying to get the user input of their details with the method inputInfo() every time the user press 1 at the menu page. the problem is after the first round of input. If I want to input another record of a person, it will keep printing out the pervious record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loops is valid after the initial case as the variables you read into are valid agaist your while loop conditions, so the prompt is never called as $name contains a valid value from the previous run.

```
inputInfo() {
nameRegex="[0-9]"
name=""
while [[ !$name =~ $nameRegex || -z $name ]]; do
        echo "Enter name"   
        read name   
    if  [[ $name =~ $nameRegex || -z $name ]]; then
            echo "Name can only contain numbers or blank"
    fi
done
```

You can just set the read variables to fail the conditions on the while loops. Setting them to zero values like the above will fix your issue.